# Cerrar sesión con Apple Sign In para no obtener credenciales null en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy utilizando [esta dependencia](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple) para crear un inicio de sesión con Apple ID

Y mi código es el mismo que el que se ve en la sección "example" de la documentación, y no estoy utilizando FireBase.

Lo que pretendo es que cada vez que inicie sesión, se envien los credenciales al backend, sin embargo, tras el primer inicio de sesión, Apple Sign In devuelve siempre los credenciales a null.

Investigando sobre este problema, he dado con estas dos respuestas.

- Utilizar FireBase para cerrar la sesión, pero parece ser que esto afecta solo a FireBase, y Apple Sign In sigue devolviendo null tras el primer inicio de sesión.
- Modificar la configuración del teléfono para que elimine la sesión, pero esto sería malo de cara al usuario.

¿Existe alguna forma de cerrar la sesión? De hecho, la clase de GoogleSignIn tiene un método para ello, y me extraña que Apple no lo tenga, o que sea tan complicado realizar esta tarea.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que realizas por favor, revisar [ask] , saludos

Comment: Hola, como dije en la pregunta el código que estoy utilizando es el mismo que el de la documentación, es decir este https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple/example